# Convert amount into negative depending on value in another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

A Table has following columns
AcctNo, Dr_Cr, Amount
1111, C, 1000
1111, D, 500

The column Dr_Cr has only two values D,C

Looking for a query which will output the following
AcctNo, Dr_Cr, Amount, Amount1
1111, C, 1000, 1000
1111,D,500, -500

(i.e. the amount should be converted to negative when the Dr_Cr = 'D')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT AcctNo, 
       Dr_Cr,
       Amount, 
       CASE 
           WHEN Dr_Cr='D' THEN -1*Amount
           ELSE Amount 
       END AS Amount1 
FROM ACCOUNTS
```

Replace `ACCOUNTS` with your table name.

Comment: Always eager to solve an SQL problem. You could mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do that is with a `CASE` statement when selecting your Amount column.

Something like:

```
SELECT ...., 
CASE WHEN Dr_Cr = 'D' THEN Amount*(-1) ELSE Amount END as Amount 
FROM ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use:

```
select
(CASE WHEN (amount) < 0 THEN 'Dr' ELSE 'Cr' END )Dr_Cr
from Your TableName
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Thanks for your answer. Please consider explaining your approach and adding some description on the statements used. Find the "edit" button below you post.